# How to scrape many dynamic urls in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape one dynamic url at a time.
What I did is that I scrape the URL from that I get from all the `href`s and then I want to scrape that URL.
What I am trying:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request 
import re

r = urllib.request.urlopen('http://i.cantonfair.org.cn/en/ExpExhibitorList.aspx?k=glassware')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
links = soup.find_all("a", href=re.compile(r"expexhibitorlist\.aspx\?categoryno=[0-9]+"))

linksfromcategories = ([link["href"] for link in links])
string = "http://i.cantonfair.org.cn/en/"

str1 = [string + x for x in linksfromcategories]
fulllinksfromcategories = '\n'.join(str1)
lfc = urllib.request.urlopen(fulllinksfromcategories).read()
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(lfc,"html.parser") 
print(soup2)
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\scarpepython.py", line 50, in <module>
  lfc = urllib.request.urlopen(fulllinksfromcategories).read()
  File "C:\Users\amanp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 162, in urlopen
  return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\amanp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 465, in open
  response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\amanp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 483, in _open
'_open', req)
  File "C:\Users\amanp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 443, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\amanp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1268, in http_open
  return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Users\amanp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1243, in do_open
  r = h.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\amanp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1174, in getresponse
response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\amanp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 282, in begin
version, status, reason = self._read_status()
 File "C:\Users\amanp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 264, in _read_status
raise BadStatusLine(line)
http.client.BadStatusLine:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str1` in your case contains a list of URLs. You are joining this list of URLs into a single string separated by newlines and then try to navigate to that mix which of course would not work.

Instead, you meant to loop over the extracted URLs one by one and navigate:

```
linksfromcategories = [string + x for x in linksfromcategories]
for link in linksfromcategories:
    print(link)
    lfc = urllib.request.urlopen(link).read()
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(lfc,"html.parser")
    print(soup2)
```

Comment: Thanks Once again. But what if I want if want again to scrape the url out of for loop ?

Comment: @AmanKumar well, since `linksfromcategories` is a list, you can get items from it by index: `lfc = urllib.request.urlopen(linksfromcategories[0]).read()`

Comment: Nice, can you tell me how to get the total no of pages and all the links ?

Answer (score 1):

this could be an option using lxml.

```
from sys import exit
from pprint import pprint

import lxml.html
import requests
import re

url = 'http://i.cantonfair.org.cn/en/ExpExhibitorList.aspx?k=glassware&page=1'
doc = requests.get(url)
root = lxml.html.fromstring(doc.text)

regexp_total_pages = re.compile(ur"Pages\s\d\/(\d+)")
text_total_pages = root.xpath('//*[@id="AspNetPager1"]/div[1]/text()')[0].strip()
total_pages = int(re.match(regexp_total_pages,text_total_pages).group(1))

all_links = list()

for i in range(1,total_pages + 1):
    url = "http://i.cantonfair.org.cn/en/ExpExhibitorList.aspx?k=glassware&page={page}".format(page=i)
    doc = requests.get(url)
    root = lxml.html.fromstring(doc.text)
    all_links.append(root.xpath('//*[@id="form1"]/div[*]/div[*]/h3/a/@href'))

pprint(all_links)
```

Output:

```
[['expCompany.aspx?corpid=0776011226',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0767408756',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0768210055',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0797720568',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0732708199',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0793210033',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0732106474',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0758010034',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0971067386',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0740321671'],
 ['expCompany.aspx?corpid=0778019678',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0856547211',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0786118468',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0836547578',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0898829143',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0785822466',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0886647641',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0965278225',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0889552449',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0757118156'],
 ['expCompany.aspx?corpid=0800629095',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0797100877',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0791001566',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0955274359',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0789803409',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0769413578',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0712314777',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0873048367',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0716520166',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1444012375'],
 ['expCompany.aspx?corpid=1020485398',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1218502245',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1197393480',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1366309374',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1204799012',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1078880722',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1367905785',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1427517382',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1377308235',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1437717128'],
 ['expCompany.aspx?corpid=1361609356',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1532524260',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1512425129',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1371110608',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1021582521',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0829323712',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0756508698',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0781315922',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0850325858',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0713405337'],
 ['expCompany.aspx?corpid=0895550135',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0736604457',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0761821937',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0853755897',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0807455302',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0763919269',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0736104221',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0796616555',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0804229227',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0746304700'],
 ['expCompany.aspx?corpid=0839047328',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0875628420',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0869651030',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0838653323',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0779107569',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0748806674',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0736602141',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0722715458',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0782910676',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0798114121'],
 ['expCompany.aspx?corpid=0830450037',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0723700490',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0889823692',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0984073042',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0726719753',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0742406942',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0742119461',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0728315987',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0818248812',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0750419352'],
 ['expCompany.aspx?corpid=0982275722',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0815756641',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0712604536',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0798617576',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0734217566',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0878728894',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0772422523',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0784607985',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0786204936',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0886423907'],
 ['expCompany.aspx?corpid=0789300431',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0779921604',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0794403082',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0769111680',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0746606839',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0896726003',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0886728390',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0841756743',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1010680461',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0837456503'],
 ['expCompany.aspx?corpid=0735317945',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0858556012',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0883227862',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0802151577',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0725403915',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0773118307',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0977967839',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0889257398',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0773003774',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0741211862'],
 ['expCompany.aspx?corpid=0944767300',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0766703225',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0807623222',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0754416485',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0716414765',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0764603066',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0757110589',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0800248632',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0747902779',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0738619647'],
 ['expCompany.aspx?corpid=1098582416',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0909669961',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0862829627',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0892328884',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0886729635',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0724805261',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0877655294',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0835853958',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0737821957',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0785019255'],
 ['expCompany.aspx?corpid=0873828585',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0735401884',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0927058069',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0794816876',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0721211392',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0741602341',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0760906105',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0904473659',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0711614568',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0753503530'],
 ['expCompany.aspx?corpid=0774108002',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0845328722',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0823848403',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0876029511',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0886827914',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0712712280',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0833854881',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0746216867',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0774704214',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0730516488'],
 ['expCompany.aspx?corpid=0716607064',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0758917403',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0763702256',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0721303394',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0828647452',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0771805641',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0741722489',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0980867582',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0790809611',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0714917484'],
 ['expCompany.aspx?corpid=0790402155',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0710118558',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0864455955',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0784706276',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0897623416',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0821453137',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0754917280',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0724600646',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0764211415',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0735008307'],
 ['expCompany.aspx?corpid=0795909343',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0850830043',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0970778277',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1075781404',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1252802513',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1236901616',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1435215908',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1469712283',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1439615100',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1245501009'],
 ['expCompany.aspx?corpid=0901974362',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1487117816',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1058881186',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0809557305',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1265998039',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1188093431',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0995572026',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1036184837',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0990573086',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1464212531'],
 ['expCompany.aspx?corpid=0858351382',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1348806571',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0822452086',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1428413902',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0879752062',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1369405760',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1256000612',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1037680042',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1062381570',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1461915811'],
 ['expCompany.aspx?corpid=1373808159',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1027382040',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1191393458',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1133389590',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0762910036',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1399206654',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1253598637',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1128889405',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1082384190',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1077881359'],
 ['expCompany.aspx?corpid=1584325065',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1131692156',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1587322969',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1251100353',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1115590386',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1541424572',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1137393378',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1069988131',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1392806069',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=0766210029'],
 ['expCompany.aspx?corpid=1143394259',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1561819111',
  'expCompany.aspx?corpid=1349307520']]
```

Comment: lxml. hmm
I am using python 3.5.1 in window 10 and I have tried to install lxml package but it fails giving error Failed building wheel for lxml and error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat.  So i am stuck with BeautifulSoup4.

Comment: Can you tell me how to get total page and url in BeautifulSoup

Comment: well , BeautifulSoup dont have Xpath selector. One way is with regexp, you can use the same regexp. Try to fix the error in windows.