# How to print element from beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Tried to get number by:

```
soop = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
span = soop.find_all('span', class_='tw-animated-number tw-animated-number--monospaced')
print(span)
```

Got output:

```
[]
```

How to get the number?

Comment: Please share the page link of the page

Comment: https://www.twitch.tv/f1nn5ter

Comment: tied of seeing this kind of question the answer is *that data are dynamic* or se here [Scrape a dynamic website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206855/scrape-a-dynamic-website?r=SearchResults&s=2|75.6172), [Scrape dynamic contents using bs4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56161382/scrape-dynamic-contents-using-bs4?r=SearchResults&s=3|69.8891), [How to scrape many dynamic urls in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35610117/how-to-scrape-many-dynamic-urls-in-python?r=SearchResults&s=16|61.9212), etc

Answer (score 0):

The data is loaded dynamically from another URL. To get actual number of viewers on this channel, you can try this script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


username = 'f1nn5ter'

url = 'https://gql.twitch.tv/gql#origin=twilight'
data = "[{\"operationName\":\"ChannelRoot_SocialMediaSpace\",\"variables\":{\"channelLogin\":\""+username+"\"},\"extensions\":{\"persistedQuery\":{\"version\":1,\"sha256Hash\":\"3cc9b2fc1ce60c0d0bd271e795e6c9d0baef0d7cb8a0f130c5311f4d045157da\"}}},{\"operationName\":\"StreamMetadata\",\"variables\":{\"channelLogin\":\""+username+"\"},\"extensions\":{\"persistedQuery\":{\"version\":1,\"sha256Hash\":\"1c719a40e481453e5c48d9bb585d971b8b372f8ebb105b17076722264dfa5b3e\"}}},{\"operationName\":\"UseViewCount\",\"variables\":{\"channelLogin\":\""+username+"\"},\"extensions\":{\"persistedQuery\":{\"version\":1,\"sha256Hash\":\"00b11c9c428f79ae228f30080a06ffd8226a1f068d6f52fbc057cbde66e994c2\"}}},{\"operationName\":\"UseLiveBroadcast\",\"variables\":{\"channelLogin\":\""+username+"\"},\"extensions\":{\"persistedQuery\":{\"version\":1,\"sha256Hash\":\"5ab2aee4bf1e768b9dc9020a9ae7ccf6f30f78b0a91d5dad504b29df4762c08a\"}}},{\"operationName\":\"Drops_ChannelDrops_User\",\"variables\":{\"login\":\""+username+"\",\"isLoggedIn\":false},\"extensions\":{\"persistedQuery\":{\"version\":1,\"sha256Hash\":\"f309b1d517d288074d50d96512059857cc67d8905d1379e414d70f7b981f2618\"}}},{\"operationName\":\"RealtimeStreamTagList\",\"variables\":{\"channelLogin\":\""+username+"\"},\"extensions\":{\"persistedQuery\":{\"version\":1,\"sha256Hash\":\"9d952e4aacd4f8bb9f159bd4d5886d72c398007249a8b09e604a651fc2f8ac17\"}}}]"
headers = {
    'Client-Id': 'kimne78kx3ncx6brgo4mv6wki5h1ko'
}

def traverse(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            if k == 'viewersCount':
                yield v
                return
            yield from traverse(v)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for v in d:
            yield from traverse(v)

d = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data).json()
print(next(traverse(d)))
```

Prints:

```
3722
```